# Linq Join on Two Conditions

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am having some trouble with a left join on two DataTables that uses multiple conditions. I am getting an error `The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'`

The error shows up on the keyword `join` just before `t2`

```
var JoinedData= ((from t1 in TableOne.AsEnumerable()
    join t2 in TableTwo.AsEnumerable() on 
        new { t1s = (string)t1["start_time"], t1r = (string)t1["reference_id"] } 
        equals 
        new { t2s = (string)t2["start_time"], t2r = (string)t2["reference_id"] }
    select new { 
                 id= (string)t1["reference_id"] 
               }
)).Distinct()
```

Everything works fine with one or the other, but when I combine them it gets the error.

Comment: probably unrelated, but your anonymous types have different property names - how can they ever be equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing with anonymous objects with same properties names:

```
    new { start_time = (string)t1["start_time"], end_time = (string)t1["reference_id"] } 
    equals 
    new { start_time = (string)t2["start_time"], end_time = (string)t2["reference_id"] }
```